# Read filenames from a text file and then make those files?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

My code is given below. Echo works fine. But, the moment I redirect output of echo to touch, I get an error "no such file or directory". Why ? How do i fix it ?
If I copy paste the output of only echo, then the file is created, but not with touch.

```
while read line           
do           
    #touch < echo -e "$correctFilePathAndName"
    echo -e "$correctFilePathAndName"           
done < $file.txt
```

Comment: Where is `$correctFilePathAndName` set? Also why not just `touch $correctFilePathAndName`?

Comment: But why does input redirect not work here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide the file name as argument and not via standard input. You can use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) via `$(…)` or `…`:

```
while read line
do
    touch "$(echo -e "$correctFilePathAndName")"
done < $file.txt
```

Comment: why does input redirect not work here ? I am new to unix bash scripting and I don't know these things.

Comment: @blasto Because `touch` does take the file as argument and not via standard input. That’s how it is designed.

Comment: @blasto Also because a redirect expects to interact with a *file*, not another command. In your example `touch < echo something` looks for a *file* named `echo` to use as input to the `touch` program. The extra stuff at the end of the line is considered to be part of the `touch` command, so your example is equivalent to `touch -e "$variable" < echo`. Touch doesn't usually understand `-e`, and would complain about that, if the shell didn't abort the command first because it can't find `echo` to feed to the standard input of `touch`...

Answer (score 8):

If you have file names in each line of your input file `file.txt` then you don't need to do any loop. You can just do:

```
touch $(<file.txt)
```

to create all the files in one single touch command.

Comment: Thanks once again anubhava.

Comment: Great answer, but be aware that this fails for large lists of files (exceeding `$MAX_ARG_STRLEN`)

Answer (score 3):

Ehm, lose the echo part... and use the correct variable name.

```
while read line; do
    touch "$line"
done < $file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
echo -e "$correctFilePathAndName" | touch
```

EDIT : Sorry correct piping is :

```
echo -e "$correctFilePathAndName" | xargs touch
```

The '<' redirects via stdin whereas touch needs the filename as an argument. xargs transforms stdin in an argument for touch.

Comment: Does not work. touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.

Comment: Sorry see EDIT which is correct. Touch uses an argument not stdin

Comment: That's really a crazy way of doing it.

Comment: Let's consider it as educational :)
And maybe the "-e" option has its importance...

Comment: @user1146332 - why do you say that ? I am new so I don't know which approaches are better.